Spark streaming `initialPosition` vs `startingPosition`?
What's the difference between initialPosition and startingPosition in spark streaming? I've gone through spark docs, delta table docs, O'Reilly guide, ... and they mention both, but not the difference between them

There is no difference between these two because both are wrong. It should be "startingVersion" or "startingTimestamp", see https://docs.delta.io/latest/delta-streaming.html#specify-initial-position
